# "Do-not-disturb" Mode for notify-osd

Tags: notify-osd, libnotify

Is there a way to enter a "Do-Not-Disturb" mode for Notify-OSD in Oneiric?  I noticed this functionality in Gnome Shell and was curious about any way to stop or silence notify-osd temporarily.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is. Totem does that when you're watching a video, for instance. I don't know how though.